# How to get current row data in beforecheckchange event

Tags: extjs4.1

I have a grid with a few columns, ajax store and so on...
And a custom checkbox column:

```
{
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        dataIndex:'checkData',
        header: 'Column with checkbox',                                
        listeners:{
            beforecheckchange:function(mthis,rowIndex,checked,eOpts){
                //here I'd like to check something like this:
                //if(currentRowData.OtherColumn == 1){
                //    return true;
                //}else{
                //    return false;
                //}                     
            }
        },
        editor: {                    
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            cls: 'x-grid-checkheader-editor'
        }
    }
```

How to get current row data in this event?
I tried:
    grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()
but it is undefined...

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe confusing this with the CheckBoxModel selector:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel

Answer (score 0):

I had to use this construction:

```
rowData = gridStore.getAt(rowIndex).getData();
```

OR

```
rowData = gridStore.getAt(rowIndex).data;
```

(what is the best variant?)

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
beforecheckchange : function(mthis,rowIndex,checked,eOpts){
var rec = your_grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
if(rec.get('OtherColumn') == 1){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}                     
}
```